# Static route in conflict with a route

Tags: debian, route, static-routes

I have a route configured.

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

I'd like to add a static route to pass traffic destined for 192.168.1.51 via a load balancer's redundant virtual interface at 192.168.1.2.

```
ip route add 192.168.1.51 mask 255.255.255.255 via 192.168.1.2
```

When I try to add the static route I get this error.

```
Error: either "to" is duplicate or "default" is garbage."
```

Is there a way around this?

Regards

Ossan

Comment: That doesn't look like a "default" route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `ip route add 192.168.1.51/32 via 192.168.1.2` accomplish what you need?

Comment: Thanks Kyle, it worked!

Strange that the 255.255.255.255 mask didn't work.